# pyqt5 mainwindow close event - recheck if user wants to close window

Tags: python-3.x, events, pyqt5

First I'm using python3.7. I first made my gui with qt designer(pyqt5) and modified it a little bit to match my needs. What I want is that whenever a user tries to close the window, a pop-up message will ask if he's sure.

I searched all over the internet but the only conclusion I got to is that:
I'm using this main function:

```
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_main_window(window)
    ui.setup_ui(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the answers I found online are using the main function:

```
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_main_window()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The differnece is that I `.show()` the `window`,  and they `.show()` the `ui`.
In addition, I call the `setup_ui(window)` with `window` that I define with `QMainWindow`.

I tried to merge the codes in various ways but unsuccessfully.

Here's my whole gui(`on_enter` and `print_from_server` aren't related):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_main_window(object):
    def __init__(self, main_window):

        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(main_window)
        self.messages_spot = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.central_widget)
        self.typing_spot = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.central_widget)
        self.add_file = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.Enter = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.central_widget)
        self.on_enter_handler = None

    def setup_ui(self, main_window):
        main_window.setObjectName("main_window")
        main_window.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        main_window.setEnabled(True)
        main_window.resize(800, 600)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(main_window.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        main_window.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        main_window.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
        main_window.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
        main_window.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("zt.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        main_window.setWindowIcon(icon)
        main_window.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        main_window.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        main_window.setDocumentMode(False)
        self.central_widget.setObjectName("central_widget")
        self.messages_spot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 731, 461))
        self.messages_spot.setUndoRedoEnabled(False)
        self.messages_spot.setReadOnly(True)
        consolas_font = QtGui.QFont()
        consolas_font.setFamily("Consolas")
        self.messages_spot.setFont(consolas_font)
        self.messages_spot.setObjectName("messages_spot")
        self.typing_spot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 529, 691, 38))
        self.typing_spot.setFont(consolas_font)
        self.typing_spot.setObjectName("typing_spot")
        self.add_file.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 529, 41, 38))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.add_file.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.add_file.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.add_file.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.add_file.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.WheelFocus)
        self.add_file.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("download.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.add_file.setIcon(icon1)
        self.add_file.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(37, 900))
        self.add_file.setObjectName("add_file")
        self.Enter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 430, 75, 23))
        self.Enter.setObjectName("Enter")
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 731, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gill Sans Ultra Bold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.Enter.raise_()
        self.typing_spot.raise_()
        self.add_file.raise_()
        self.messages_spot.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        main_window.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.Enter.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_enter())
        self.typing_spot.returnPressed.connect(self.Enter.click)

        self.retranslate_ui(main_window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(main_window)

    def retranslate_ui(self, main_window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        main_window.setWindowTitle(_translate("main_window", "ZoomieTalks"))
        self.Enter.setText(_translate("main_window", "Enter"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("main_window", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:28pt;\">ZoomieTalks</span></p></body></html>"))

    def on_enter(self):
        """Executing protocol to send messages each time the Enter button is clicked"""
        text = self.typing_spot.text()
        if text.isspace() is False and text != '':
            # self.to_server = text
            if self.on_enter_handler is not None:
                print(f"calling on_enter_handler({text})")
                self.on_enter_handler(text)
            # self.messages_spot.insertPlainText(f'•  You: {text}\r\n')
            self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
            self.typing_spot.clear()

    def print_from_server(self, text):
        """Printing messages from server in GUI"""
        if text.isspace() is False and text != '':
            print(f"printing from server: {text}")
            self.messages_spot.insertPlainText(f'•  {text}\r\n')
            self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().maximum())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_main_window(window)
    ui.setup_ui(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The "real" source of the problem is that you should never, *never* edit the contents of a file generated from Designer. **NEVER**. Please, carefully read the guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to know more about it. Then, regenerate the ui file, create a new file for your program and `import` those files as explained in the above link, then override the [`closeEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent). I'd answer your question, but I can't see no reference to close events, so I really don't know where to put it.

Comment: I did read the guide lines but I'm required to use classes correctly. The designer sets the object vars in the setupUi and not in an __init__() func so I'm afraid I'll lose points for that... Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You won't lose anything if you follow those guidelines. On the contrary, if you keep editing files created with pyuic you'll lose a lot of your time instead.